# Scrapy - SgmlLinkExtractor pass href text in addition to href to process_value callback

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I would like to add support to links that do not contain the words I'm after but the href text does contain.

I would like to be able to extract the href text as well and pass it as second argument to process_value callback.

Does anyone know how to achieve such things?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a BaseSpider and extract links based on any criteria you want.

Just to give you an idea:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        links = hxs.select('//a')
        for link in links:
            href = link.select('@href').extract()[0]
            text = links.select('text()').extract()[0]
                # I make an assumption here that you want text() instead of @href here
                if text == 'something':
                        yield Request(href, callback = self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        return #return your item here
```

Comment: My scrapper is using the SgmlLinkExtractor.
I would like to add an option to pass href text to the process_value callback function.

Comment: No ideas?
Is it easy to patch SgmlLinkExtractor to extract the href text as well?

Comment: I was convinced to use another scrapper to achieve such goal therefore I accept this solution.

10x